# Shamir's Secret Sharing for Windows?

Tags: windows, secret-sharing

Is there a good implementation of Shamir's Secret Sharing for Windows? I would like to securely transfer files over multiple channels and ensure that only the recipient receiving ALL (and possibly most of) the parts is able to uncover the original files.

Comment: You can use the many Python or Java implementations. But my guess is that you want a Windows binary, which makes this question a request for a specific tool (which is off-topic). Am I correct?

Comment: Do you know a python implementation that you could trust more than any other and that could work no files?

Comment: Unfortunately, recommendations are off-topic, and I'm not sure anyone would risk recommending a script.